# GStreamer sendonly to multiple WebRTC clients

Tags: c++, webrtc, video-streaming, gstreamer

I've been trying to setup a simple sendonly WebRTC client with GStreamer but I'm having issues with getting the actual video to display on the WebRTC receiver side. I am new to both GStreamer and WebRTC.

I'm using the examples from https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-examples/-/tree/master/webrtc to try and come up with a combination of certain parts. I've had 1:1 communication working but I wanted to introduce the rooms so I can have more clients viewing the "view-only" stream from GStreamer.

My current code is based on the [multiparty-sendrecv](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-examples/-/tree/master/webrtc/multiparty-sendrecv/gst) example where I swapped out the audio for video. Furthermore, I'm using a modified version of the [signalling server](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-examples/-/tree/master/webrtc/signalling) and a modified version of the [javascript webrtc client](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-examples/-/tree/master/webrtc/sendrecv/js). If necessary I could provide code for all of the above, but to keep things simple I won't. This is because I don't think the problem lies in either the signalling server or webrtc client, because the ICE candidates have been successfully negotiated along with the SDP offer & answer according to `chrome://webrtc-internals/`. See the image below.

[image: ICE candidates successfully negotiated]

In order to figure out what's going on I've exported a graph that shows the GStreamer pipeline after a user has joined the room and was added to the pipeline. See graph below.

[image]

As far as I can tell I should be receiving video data on my frontend, but I'm not. I've had a single weird case where the videotestsrc **did** show up, but I haven't been able to reproduce it. But because of this, it makes me think that the pipeline itself isn't neccesarily wrong, but perhaps we're dealing with some kind of race condition.

I've added the modified example of multiparty-sendrecv below, please take a look at it. Most of the methods have purposely been left out due to Stackoverflow's character limit.

**Main functions**

```js
static void
handle_media_stream(GstPad* pad, GstElement* pipe, const char* convert_name,
    const char* sink_name)
{
    GstPad* qpad;
    GstElement* q, * conv, * sink;
    GstPadLinkReturn ret;

    q = gst_element_factory_make("queue", NULL);
    g_assert_nonnull(q);
    conv = gst_element_factory_make(convert_name, NULL);
    g_assert_nonnull(conv);
    sink = gst_element_factory_make(sink_name, NULL);
    g_assert_nonnull(sink);
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipe), q, conv, sink, NULL);
    gst_element_sync_state_with_parent(q);
    gst_element_sync_state_with_parent(conv);
    gst_element_sync_state_with_parent(sink);
    gst_element_link_many(q, conv, sink, NULL);

    qpad = gst_element_get_static_pad(q, "sink");

    ret = gst_pad_link(pad, qpad);
    g_assert_cmpint(ret, == , GST_PAD_LINK_OK);
}

static void
on_incoming_decodebin_stream(GstElement* decodebin, GstPad* pad,
    GstElement* pipe)
{
    GstCaps* caps;
    const gchar* name;

    if (!gst_pad_has_current_caps(pad)) {
        g_printerr("Pad '%s' has no caps, can't do anything, ignoring\n",
            GST_PAD_NAME(pad));
        return;
    }

    caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(pad);
    name = gst_structure_get_name(gst_caps_get_structure(caps, 0));

    if (g_str_has_prefix(name, "video")) {
        handle_media_stream(pad, pipe, "videoconvert", "autovideosink");
    }
    else if (g_str_has_prefix(name, "audio")) {
        handle_media_stream(pad, pipe, "audioconvert", "autoaudiosink");
    }
    else {
        g_printerr("Unknown pad %s, ignoring", GST_PAD_NAME(pad));
    }
}

static void
on_incoming_stream(GstElement* webrtc, GstPad* pad, GstElement* pipe)
{
    GstElement* decodebin;
    GstPad* sinkpad;

    if (GST_PAD_DIRECTION(pad) != GST_PAD_SRC)
        return;

    decodebin = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", NULL);
    g_signal_connect(decodebin, "pad-added",
        G_CALLBACK(on_incoming_decodebin_stream), pipe);
    gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipe), decodebin);
    gst_element_sync_state_with_parent(decodebin);

    sinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad(decodebin, "sink");
    gst_pad_link(pad, sinkpad);
    gst_object_unref(sinkpad);
}

static void
add_peer_to_pipeline(const gchar* peer_id, gboolean offer)
{
    int ret;
    gchar* tmp;
    GstElement* tee, * webrtc, * q;
    GstPad* srcpad, * sinkpad;

    tmp = g_strdup_printf("queue-%s", peer_id);
    q = gst_element_factory_make("queue", tmp);
    g_free(tmp);
    webrtc = gst_element_factory_make("webrtcbin", peer_id);
    g_object_set(webrtc, "bundle-policy", GST_WEBRTC_BUNDLE_POLICY_MAX_BUNDLE, NULL);

    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), q, webrtc, NULL);

    srcpad = gst_element_get_static_pad(q, "src");
    g_assert_nonnull(srcpad);
    sinkpad = gst_element_get_request_pad(webrtc, "sink_%u");
    g_assert_nonnull(sinkpad);
    ret = gst_pad_link(srcpad, sinkpad);
    g_assert_cmpint(ret, == , GST_PAD_LINK_OK);
    gst_object_unref(srcpad);
    gst_object_unref(sinkpad);

    tee = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline), "videotee");
    g_assert_nonnull(tee);
    srcpad = gst_element_get_request_pad(tee, "src_%u");
    g_assert_nonnull(srcpad);
    gst_object_unref(tee);
    sinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad(q, "sink");
    g_assert_nonnull(sinkpad);
    ret = gst_pad_link(srcpad, sinkpad);
    g_assert_cmpint(ret, == , GST_PAD_LINK_OK);
    gst_object_unref(srcpad);
    gst_object_unref(sinkpad);

    /* This is the gstwebrtc entry point where we create the offer and so on. It
     * will be called when the pipeline goes to PLAYING.
     * XXX: We must connect this after webrtcbin has been linked to a source via
     * get_request_pad() and before we go from NULL->READY otherwise webrtcbin
     * will create an SDP offer with no media lines in it. */
    if (offer)
        g_signal_connect(webrtc, "on-negotiation-needed",
            G_CALLBACK(on_negotiation_needed), (gpointer)peer_id);

    /* We need to transmit this ICE candidate to the browser via the websockets
     * signalling server. Incoming ice candidates from the browser need to be
     * added by us too, see on_server_message() */
    g_signal_connect(webrtc, "on-ice-candidate",
        G_CALLBACK(send_ice_candidate_message), (gpointer)peer_id);
    /* Incoming streams will be exposed via this signal */
    g_signal_connect(webrtc, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(on_incoming_stream),
        pipeline);

    /* Set to pipeline branch to PLAYING */
    ret = gst_element_sync_state_with_parent(q);
    g_assert_true(ret);
    ret = gst_element_sync_state_with_parent(webrtc);
    g_assert_true(ret);

    GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE(GST_BIN(pipeline), GST_DEBUG_GRAPH_SHOW_ALL, "pipeline");
}

static gboolean
start_pipeline(void)
{
    GstStateChangeReturn ret;
    GError* error = NULL;

    /* NOTE: webrtcbin currently does not support dynamic addition/removal of
     * streams, so we use a separate webrtcbin for each peer, but all of them are
     * inside the same pipeline. We start by connecting it to a fakesink so that
     * we can preroll early. */
    /*pipeline = gst_parse_launch("tee name=videotee ! queue ! fakesink "
        "videotestsrc is-live=true pattern=ball ! videoconvert ! queue ! vp8enc deadline=1 ! rtpvp8pay ! "
        "queue ! " RTP_CAPS_VP8 "96 ! videotee. ", &error);*/
    pipeline = gst_parse_launch("tee name=videotee ! queue ! fakesink "
        "videotestsrc is-live=true pattern=ball ! videoconvert ! queue ! vp8enc deadline=1 ! rtpvp8pay ! "
        "queue ! " RTP_CAPS_VP8 "96 ! videotee. ", &error);

    if (error) {
        g_printerr("Failed to parse launch: %s\n", error->message);
        g_error_free(error);
        goto err;
    }

    g_print("Starting pipeline, not transmitting yet\n");
    ret = gst_element_set_state(GST_ELEMENT(pipeline), GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)
        goto err;

    return TRUE;

err:
    g_print("State change failure\n");
    if (pipeline)
        g_clear_object(&pipeline);
    return FALSE;
}

/*
 * When we join a room, we are responsible for calling by starting negotiation
 * with each peer in it by sending an SDP offer and ICE candidates.
 */
static void
do_join_room(const gchar* text)
{
    gint ii, len;
    gchar** peer_ids;

    if (app_state != ROOM_JOINING) {
        cleanup_and_quit_loop("ERROR: Received ROOM_OK when not calling",
            ROOM_JOIN_ERROR);
        return;
    }

    app_state = ROOM_JOINED;
    g_print("Room joined\n");
    /* Start recording, but not transmitting */
    if (!start_pipeline()) {
        cleanup_and_quit_loop("ERROR: Failed to start pipeline", ROOM_CALL_ERROR);
        return;
    }

    peer_ids = g_strsplit(text, " ", -1);
    g_assert_cmpstr(peer_ids[0], == , "ROOM_OK");
    len = g_strv_length(peer_ids);
    /* There are peers in the room already. We need to start negotiation
     * (exchange SDP and ICE candidates) and transmission of media. */
    if (len > 1 && strlen(peer_ids[1]) > 0) {
        g_print("Found %i peers already in room\n", len - 1);
        app_state = ROOM_CALL_OFFERING;
        for (ii = 1; ii < len; ii++) {
            gchar* peer_id = g_strdup(peer_ids[ii]);
            g_print("Negotiating with peer %s\n", peer_id);
            /* This might fail asynchronously */
            call_peer(peer_id);
            peers = g_list_prepend(peers, peer_id);
        }
    }

    g_strfreev(peer_ids);
    return;
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    GOptionContext* context;
    GError* error = NULL;

    context = g_option_context_new("- gstreamer webrtc sendrecv demo");
    g_option_context_add_main_entries(context, entries, NULL);
    g_option_context_add_group(context, gst_init_get_option_group());
    if (!g_option_context_parse(context, &argc, &argv, &error)) {
        g_printerr("Error initializing: %s\n", error->message);
        return -1;
    }

    if (!check_plugins())
        return -1;

    if (!room_id) {
        g_printerr("--room-id is a required argument\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (!local_id)
        local_id = g_strdup_printf("%s-%i", g_get_user_name(),
            g_random_int_range(10, 10000));
    /* Sanitize by removing whitespace, modifies string in-place */
    g_strdelimit(local_id, " \t\n\r", '-');

    g_print("Our local id is %s\n", local_id);

    if (!server_url)
        server_url = g_strdup(default_server_url);

    /* Don't use strict ssl when running a localhost server, because
     * it's probably a test server with a self-signed certificate */
    {
        GstUri* uri = gst_uri_from_string(server_url);
        if (g_strcmp0("localhost", gst_uri_get_host(uri)) == 0 ||
            g_strcmp0("127.0.0.1", gst_uri_get_host(uri)) == 0)
            strict_ssl = FALSE;
        gst_uri_unref(uri);
    }

    loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

    connect_to_websocket_server_async();

    g_main_loop_run(loop);

    gst_element_set_state(GST_ELEMENT(pipeline), GST_STATE_NULL);
    g_print("Pipeline stopped\n");

    gst_object_unref(pipeline);
    g_free(server_url);
    g_free(local_id);
    g_free(room_id);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In my opinion `multiparty-sendrecv` example is a little bit wrong. I've did my own implementation for video based on it:
https://github.com/WebRTSP/RtStreaming/blob/master/GstRtStreaming/GstWebRTCPeer2.cpp https://github.com/WebRTSP/RtStreaming/blob/master/GstRtStreaming/GstStreamingSource.cpp

Comment: demo based on that code: http://clock.webrtsp.org:5080/. Binaries https://snapcraft.io/rtsp-to-webrtsp https://snapcraft.io/webrtsp-clock

Comment: And I don't think it will be easy to find problem without debugging... It's too many possible reasons...

Comment: @RSATom thanks for the info, I'll check out your own implementation

Comment: can you please share the debug logs using GST_DEBUG=3,*webrtc*:7

Comment: Can you please post the sdp answer and offer

Comment: I am facing a similar problem

Comment: Did u get around this problem?

Comment: nvm mine got fixed by setting the webrtc bundle-policy to max-compat